# Boost Regex not playing welll with Snow leopard

Tags: regex, boost, boost-regex

So I inherited code written in C++ that uses the Boost library. I could compile (using Code Blocks) and run the code on Linux Ubuntu but when I ported it over to the mac and installed the boost library, I can compile it using code blocks (and specifying the location of the regex libraries) but it won't run.

It just gives me the error:

$ ./BLAH_PD

dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_regex.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/spinach/Desktop/B/BLAH/bin/Release/./BLAH_PD
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap

I'm not sure what to do next but any help would be greatly appreciated.

David

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to include the path where you installed the compiled Boost libs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow [these](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) directions?
Boost.Regex is not a header only library. You will need to install/compile the .dynlib. If you did this, did you remember to correctly link it? (-llibboost_regex -LPATH_TO_BOOST_BIN)